# Steps to get $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \sqrt{1 + 1/x^2}$

Tags: limits

I'd like to get a step by step answer for the following:

> $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \sqrt{1 + \frac 1 {x^2}}$$

Comment: Can you share what you've tried, and explain what you're having trouble with? Do you mean this? $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}}$$

Comment: Yes exactly, I tried multiplying both the numerator and denominator by (1+1/x^2)^(1/2) but I then get stuck on trying to clear it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  Note that for positive $x$ we have
$$\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}=\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{x^2+1}.$$ 
You can probably take over from here.

**Remark:** Note that if $x$ is *negative*, then $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=-x$. So the limit from the *left* is $-1$.

Comment: Thanks, this would explain it. I still do not get that equality, probably a property of square roots I can't remember, I will check them out !

Comment: We have $1+\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}$ (brought to common denominator). And if $a$ and $b$ are positive, then $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\cdot\sqrt{a}$.